# Swift4 : How to use reloadData & deselectRow in UITableViewController?

Tags: uitableview, swift4, reloaddata, reloadrows

I try to reloadData on UITableView at viewWillApper.
But deselectRow Animation is not working well.
How can I do reloadData & deselectRow animation?

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    self.tableView.reloadData()
    if let indexPathForSelectedRow = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            self.tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPathForSelectedRow, animated: true)
    }
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}
```

and below is different. Fade animation duration is little bit short.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    if (self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow != nil){
        self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!], with: .fade)
    } 

    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}
```

Comment: I would advise not to reload data in this case at all. If you only want to update the contents of the cells, just iterate over `visibleCells` and update their contents directly.

Comment: Did you try just using `deselectRow(at:)` and no reload of any kind?

Comment: @rmaddy thank you for advice. In case using deselectRow(at:) and no reload is not to update the contents of the cell...

Comment: @Sulthan thank you! The way you advice works. I show succeed code below code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of reloading the whole table, you can just update the contents of the cell directly:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let indices = self.tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows ?? []
    for index in indices {
       guard let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(index) else { continue }
       cell.textLabel?.text = textDataArray[index.row]
    }

    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can update cell with deselect rows animation.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    var indexes = self.tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows
        var i = 0
        for var records in self.tableView.visibleCells{
            records.textLabel?.text = textDataArray[indexes![i].row]
        i = i + 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Huh, this is not safe. You shouldn't index `visibleCells` like this, you should: `indexes.forEach {  let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow($0) }`.

Comment: I have added an answer without that nasty indexing.

Comment: @Sulthan Great. thank you. My code is not safe, so sometime crashed.